# How I can create jQuery object in TypeScript for `window` and `document`?

Tags: jquery, typescript

How I can create jQuery object in TypeScript for `window` and `document`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set `JQuery<Window>` type instead of `JQuery`:

[image]